# STS 3.8.4 unable to generate setters and getters index:5 size:5 error

Tags: spring-tool-suite

In STS version 3.8.3 and 3.8.4, I am unable to generate setters and getters. It is giving the following error:

> Generating getters and setters failed Index:5, Size:5

[image]

Comment: do you have any additional plugins installed (like Groovy-Eclipse or Lombok)? And do you see an error message in the Error Log View? A full stack trace would help a lot to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, it's because of `lombok` dependency.

Open **STS.ini**, comment `#-javaagent:lombok.jar` and restart STS.
Now you will be able to generate getters and setters.